# Pimcore - How to create custom table via custom plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, pimcore

I am trying to create **pimcore custom plugin** .

I gone through its documentation and so far i have created demo plugin and its working fine .

Now i want to create custom table via plugin and needs to store data in the custom table, but not getting idea how to achieve that ? **I know in plugin.php -> install method , we need to define database related queries**.

But how to write those queries in pimcore way that I am not getting .

I have already try below code :

```
 public static function install()
    {
       // sql to create table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50),
        reg_date TIMESTAMP
        )";
        // implement your own logic here
        return true;
    }
```

Hope the question make sense.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42159793/988957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to then actually execute that query on your DB. The Install method is what is called when a user clicks the install button for the plugin in the Extensions panel. Your query looks good, but you need to actually run it now. Try something like this:

```
$db = \Pimcore\Db::get();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";
$db->query($sql);
return true;
```

Instead of just returning true, it would be a good idea to check to make sure the table was created. You could try something like this:

```
$result = $db->describeTable("MyGuests");
if($result){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

but there are plenty of other ways of checking to make sure it was successful.

## UPDATE

If you only have the red uninstall button, you need to adjust your plugin's isInstalled method. The plugin decides whether to run the install or uninstall method depending on whether or not the plugin is reporting it is installed. If your isInstalled method is returning true, you will have the option to uninstall. If it is returning false, you will have the option to install.

That said, you should check to make sure the table exists in your isInstalled method, and return true or false accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Josh Palan , Thanks for your answer i have already done that but issue here is my install method is not calling , if i only right echo in install method still its not showing because method is not calling . Dont know the issue :(

Comment: When you say it isn't being called, do you mean when you click the green install button in the extensions panel? There should be two options, one for enable and one for install. Once it's enabled, the plugin checks its isInstalled method to see if the plugin is considered install. If it's returning true, the button will be like a red x uninstall button. If it's returning false, you should have the option to click a green install button. Doing so should call the install method...

Comment: Any news? If my answer helped please feel free to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Accepted it !! but still my install method is not called . I have created custom plugin !! then from upload i have upload it . but install method not called

Comment: After uploading it, you need to make sure it is enabled. Once it is enabled, you should have the option to click the green "plus" install button. THAT'S when the install method is called; Not when you upload it, not when you enable it, ONLY BY CLICKING THE INSTALL BUTTON.

Comment: When i uploading zip file of plugin from extensions pimcore backend , no green plus button show there . It directly shows red circlet button on both enable/disabled and install/uninstall

Comment: This is because your "isInstalled" method is returning true! You need it to return false if it isn't installed, and true if it is.

Comment: So what exactly i need to do it for that ?

Comment: Updated my answer!